# How should i use mockito for object inside objects and then value

Tags: java, junit, mockito

if i have code like this object1.object2.object3 and then object3 returning value. But problem is that i don't have Database connectivity to return that values and this objects are coming from import file(.jar), i need to test that objects return correct values or not. 
can any help me to test this framework using mockito and junit.

Comment: Could you please put some sample code?

Comment: Nicktar's answer is definitely what most people will tell you. If you really need the entire object tree, you could use a pre-defined object structure saved as JSON, load that with Jackson in your test, and then run tests against that object tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets take an example code

```
String streetNumber = project.getEmployeeById("1001").getAddress().getStreetNumber();
```

Now this code has to be refactored as

```
Employee emp = project.getEmployeeById("1001");
Address address = emp.getAddress();
String streetNumber = address.getStreetNumber();
```

in your test case you can Mock the emp and adsress objects

```
Employee emp = mockito.mock(Employee.class);
Address add = new Address();
add.setStreetNumber("123-gg");
mockito.when(project.getEmployeeById("1001")).thenReturn(emp);
mockito.when(emp.getAddress()).thenReturn("add");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're writing a unit test and not an integration test, just mock object2 and be done with it. The test should neither know or care if there even is an object 3.

If you're calling object3 directly, you're in violation of the Law of Demeter and should fix that issue first.

Law of Demeter:

- Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units: only units "closely" related to the current unit.
- Each unit should only talk to its friends; don't talk to strangers.
- Only talk to your immediate friends.

from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). In other words. Code should only interact with objects it created itself or that were injected directly into it.